# Does $f _n \to f $ pointwise imply $f _n $ converges to $f $ in $L ^p $ norm if $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy in $L^p$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

If a sequence $\{f _n \}$ of functions converges pointwise to a function $f $ does this imply that if the same sequence is a Cauchy sequence in some $L^p $ norm then it converges to the same function $f $ in the same $L^p $ norm? I believe so but how is this motivated?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not true. Take $f_n$ as the indicator function of the interval $[n,n+1]$: then $f_n\to 0$ pointwise, but $\|f_n\|_p = 1$.

Even if the space $X$ has a finite measure, for instance $X=(0,1)$, by taking $f_n$ as $n^{\alpha}$ times the indicator function of $\left(1-\frac{1}{n},1\right)$ we get a counter-example.

Comment: Ok thanks, what if the space $X $ has finite measure? ie I have a specific example where $X =[0,1]$

Comment: @Alexander: answer updated to show the "travelling interval" counter-example for sets with finite measure, too.

Comment: I see now that my question wasn't formulated clearly, so no need to edit this answer but I still post this here, since it is related and what made me ask the question in the first place.



If a sequence $\{f _n \} $ converges poitwise (or just a.e.) to some funtion $f $ and assuming $\{f _n \} $ also converges in $L^p $, then it must converge to the same $f  $ in the $L^p $ space to.  This follows since convergence in $L^p $ implies a a.e. convergent subsequence to the same function.